# problems with class tester and calling methods

Tags: java

So my program is object oriented and I am getting compiler errors(below). I am trying to call all of my methods in my tester.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `System.out.println( cyl.getHeight);`

with

```
System.out.println( cyl.getHeight());
```

Same is the case with `System.out.println( cyl.getRadius);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add circular brackets `()` while calling methods, otherwise those will be treated as fields. And you don't have fields with name `getRadius/getHeight` in your `Cylinder` class, instead those are methods. So do the following changes:

```
 cyl.getRadius
```

should be

```
 cyl.getRadius()
```

Similarly:

```
cyl.getHeight
```

should be

```
cyl.getHeight()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in main method as follows:

From

```
System.out.println( cyl.getRadius);

System.out.println( cyl.getHeight);
```

To

```
System.out.println( cyl.getRadius());

System.out.println( cyl.getHeight());
```